# Add 0 in a string of characters in R

Tags: r, string, insert

I have a dataset that has column wells A1-A24, B1-B24 all through P24. I would like to add a 0 to the middle of any wells with only 2 characters. For example, A1 would become A01 and B24 would stay B24.

This is an example of what I have:

data.frame

```
1   A1
2   A2
3   A3
4   A4
5   A5
6   A6
7   A7
8   A8
9   A9
10  A10
11  A11
12  A12
```

This is what I want:

data.frame

```
1   A01
2   A02
3   A03
4   A04
5   A05
6   A06
7   A07
8   A08
9   A09
10  A10
11  A11
12  A12
```

Comment: Why it's needed to have the 0 there?

Comment: I need it in order to merge files. Basically I have a file that has plate and well in one column and everything is with a 0 and the other file has plate and well without the 0. I need the 0 in both files to merge them appropriately.                                                          I know it's something that would be easy enough in excel, but if there's a way in R that would be nice.

Comment: Should you add then R as the tag, because I had no clue what language you wanted to use.

Comment: added to tag and title

Comment: You see? Minutes after you place it with the correct tag, you get an answer from domain experts as they get notified about your question.

Answer (score 1):

We can do like this with `gsub` + `sprintf`

```
transform(
  df,
  y = sprintf("%s%02i", gsub("\\d", "", y), as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", y)))
)
```

which gives

```
    x   y
1   1 A01
2   2 A02
3   3 A03
4   4 A04
5   5 A05
6   6 A06
7   7 A07
8   8 A08
9   9 A09
10 10 A10
11 11 A11
12 12 A12
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = 1:12, y = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", 
"A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```